# Не работает onMousePressed у ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте! Вот код

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    System.out.println("pressed");
});

sp.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
    System.out.println("dragged");
});
```

Но почему-то это не работает, ничего не происходит при нажатии по ScrollPane. Что не так?

Comment: потому, что setOnMousePressed принимает EventHandler, а вы передаете три точки.

Comment: Подробней опишите вашу ситуацию и покажите больше кода. По вашим двум строчкам и расплывчатому "не работает" понять ничего нельзя.

Comment: @Виктор если вам так спокойнее... Но не думаю, что это вам поможет.

Comment: чтобы  нажать на sctollPane её как минимум надо отрисовать на экране, сделайте это и попробуйте нажать.

Comment: @Виктор сложно это представить, но до этого я догадался, но всё равно не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё сработает, если добавлять слушатели не к самому ScrollPane, а к его контенту, т.е. вот:

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
Node content = sp.getContent();
content.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
//Ваши действия
});
```

Comment: Хорошо, запомню. Ваш код не проверял, но доверяю. Спасибо за ответ для общественности, ставлю +1 за ответ, а за вопрос уже поставил +1.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вариант с ананимным классом:

```
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler() {
public void handle (Event event) {
System.out.println("X: " + ((MouseEvent) event).getX() + " Y: " + (MouseEvent) event).getY());
}
});
```

А лучше всего имплементируйтесь от интерфейса `EventHandler` и реализуйте его метод `handle` и в нем пишите что вам надо, а при вызове метода
`sp.setOnMousePressed(this)` просто укажите конструктору ключевое слово `this`.

Comment: Это как раз и не работает, просто ничего не происходит...

Comment: @ProstoCoder значит вы что то не так делаете в своем коде, я не экстрасенс, что бы знать, что вы хотите от своего кода. Предлагаю вам отредактировать ваш вопрос таким образом, что бы для тех кто пытается прочесть его и помочь было понятно, что вы хотите от своего кода добиться. И еще раз, попробуйте все таки имплементировать интерфес `EventHandler`

Comment: Всё я делаю так, видишь ли просто надо добавлять слушатель не к самому скролу, а к контенту скрола, спасибо

Comment: @ProstoCoder Просьба опубликовать ваш ответ, если мой вам не помог. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот, если интересно